# Drawing something over a previous drawing results in low quality

Tags: c#, graphics, draw

In my application I draw a blue arrow and after a while I need to change it's color to green so I draw it again with a green pen. When the user clicks something the arrow must go back to its primal color so I draw the arrow again with the blue pen. All this results in a pixelated arrow although I have set .SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality. I can't use clear on graphics because I have drawn several shapes on the panel. Help!
The arrow is drawn using the drawlines method:

```
Graphics kanvas = pnlKanvas.CreateGraphics();
kanvas.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

Point[] arrow_points = { //... };                  

kanvas.DrawLines(pen, arrow_points);
```

I repeat the above 2-3 times, each time changing the pen's color. This gives me a pixelated arrow although I want it smooth. I can't clear the panel and redraw it because I have drawn several shapes on it.

Comment: please read ["How To Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you meant by low quality? Post your drawing code.

Comment: By low quality I mean a pixelated arrow. The line is not smooth...

Comment: Well sure if you keep drawing over things, it will keep getting blurrier and blurrier.  You need to re-draw with a blank canvas again to get rid of those earlier arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to clear and redraw the arrow. You can look into the `Invalidate` method to clear a certain region or rectangle on your `pnlKanvas`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: It's not what I had in mind but it will do. Thanks!